# One class for one view

Tags: iphone, oop

This may be a foolish question.but I want to know,,,,

In my iPhone Application I have so many classes and Xib files (Like 12 to 15).Is it ok to have it like that???...

Is there any limitation for number of classes......?????.....

Does it affect the performance of the app????....

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388021

Comment: Not a duplicate.  That other question asks whether it is better to use NIBs or create views programmatically.  This question is about the number of classes/NIBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually a good practice to keep individual xibs for individual screens.

If your application has more functionality, then obviously you would have more code.
Just make sure you organize & refactor the code properly.

As for performance, it would improve when you "lazy load" and release properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's OK to have it like that.  If there is common code between the classes, it would be a good idea to extract common superclasses.

As far as performance goes, you should try to "lazy load" the views; that is, don't load a NIB until you actually need to display that view. If you try to load all NIBs at app startup, then it will take longer for the app to launch.